# How do I use same html code on various php files?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I'm doing statistics web-app with **Highcharts** and **PHP** that retrieving data from MySQL and encoding it in **JSON**. For now, I have various **php-data** files for each stat, and it's OK.

The problem is that I also did various pages for each stat, which I think is not correct way to solve problems. On pages I have same HTML code, the differences only in **JS** piece of **Highcharts** and title of the page.

**Question** - can I have just one page for everything, just changing JS and title on menu-click?

**UPDATE**: Thanks for answers, require and include are good! But what about my second question? Can I change **JS** piece of code if I click on some button?

So then my site would have just 1 page and various **php-data**. On include variant I'm anyway would have a lot of pages, cause **Highcharts** settings **JS** is unique for every stat.

Comment: Make one page and use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to load data for your charts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dmitry! Nu, ili esli ugodno, spasibo. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).
Your html can then go into a seperate file which you can include in all your other pages.

For the title you just use a variable:

```
<title><?= $site_title ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use '[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)' statement in PHP to include file with the HTML code.

```
include 'filename.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have.

For the repeating code, copy your repeating code to yoursript.php and  use:

```
include 'yourscript.php'
```

on all pages you want you script to appear